# Creating seperate nav bars for different Devise scopes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have three separate logins for my app:

routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :visitors, controllers: { registrations: 'visitor/registrations' }
  ## Visitors Authentication Scope ##
    devise_scope :visitor do
      authenticated :visitor do
        root 'properties#index', as: :visitor_authenticated_root
      end
      unauthenticated :visitor do
        root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :visitor_unauthenticated_root
      end
    end
  ## END Visitors Authentication Scope ##

  devise_for :admins, controllers: { registrations: 'admin/registrations' }
  ## Administration Authentication Scope ##
    devise_scope :admin do
      authenticated :admin do
        root 'properties#index', as: :admin_authenticated_root
      end
      unauthenticated :admin do
        root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :admin_unauthenticated_root
      end
    end
  ## END Administration Authentication Scope ##

  devise_for :residents, controllers: { registrations: 'resident/registrations' }
  ## Residents Authentication Scope ##
    devise_scope :resident do
      authenticated :resident do
        root 'properties#index', as: :resident_authenticated_root
      end
      unauthenticated :resident do
        root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :resident_unauthenticated_root
      end
    end
  ## END Residents Authentication Scope ##
```

Currently they all point to `properties#index`. The admin scope will point to an admin page as the route, but each of these will have different navbar functionality, and different view layouts.

I would usually use an `if`/`else` statement if I was using boolean values to set my user types, however I created individual models for this.

How can I set-up different layouts? I read some articles but not many of them make sense, or do not do what I am trying to accomplish.

I am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make some partials and use `if` statements like:

```
if signed_in?
  if current_visitor
     = render 'path/to/visitor/navbar'
  if current_admin
     = render 'path/to/admin/navbar'
  if current_resident
     = render 'path/to/resident/navbar'
```

Comment: So could this also work like above using the if statements in the application layout page or are partials required here? I would like the  Mac bar to extend across the application depending on the type of user ( visitor, admin or resident )?